# formatting trendline using setoption() in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Apps Script to create a scatterplot with a trendline.  [I have taken an idea from Google Charts API on how to create the trendline](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines#Example4), and this has been successful.  But, the approach to *formatting the trendline* does not work as the Charts API describes.  I have used setOption("trendlines", "0: {}") to create my trendline, but it does not matter what I put in between the curly brackets, the formatting that I add there doesn't seem to work.  I would  like the trendline to have smaller points than the actual, plotted points of the scatterplot, and I would like the trendline series to be black.  If I can successfully format the trendline, then this would solve the problem of many high school science teachers who are trying to use Google Drive as a real alternative to Excel in their classes.

This is my code:

```
function scatterMe(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var chart = sheet.newChart().asScatterChart()
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:B500"))
  .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)

  //this is the code that builds the trendline... the example CSS code at 
  //https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines
  //does not seem to have any effect when I add it in between the curly braces.
  .setOption('trendlines', '0: {}')

  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following code (sample data) I can make some changes, such as color, line width, among others.

```js
function scatterMe() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];

  var trendlinesopt = {
    0: {
      color: 'black',
      lineWidth: 6,
      opacity: 0.2,
      labelInLegend: 'Test data',
      visibleInLegend: true
    }
  };
  var chart = sheet.newChart().asScatterChart()
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A1:B12"))
  .setPosition(3, 4, 0, 0)

  //this is the code that builds the trendline... the example CSS code at 
  //https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines
  //does not seem to have any effect when I add it in between the curly braces.
  .setOption('trendlines', trendlinesopt)

  .build();

  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Jenn, to clarify here, the difference is wchiquito is adding the option as an object instead of a string.  Add the option like this `.setOption('trendlines', {0: {}})` to make it work.

Comment: I would like to mark that this answer is exactly what I need, but I need 15 reputation for that.  So, in long form: this is exactly right, and I appreciate the time that you took to answer the problem so thoroughly!  There are going to be a large number of science teachers who are grateful.

Comment: @Jenn, a pleasure to help.

Comment: Has anyone else found that the lineWidth option doesn't make any difference?