# Google Sheets insert scatterplot + trendline with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I have a data series in A1:B20 and want to insert a scatterplot with a trendline for this data. I can create the scatterplot no problem, but I cannot get the trendline to appear. Other options (like title) work, but I can't get the trendline.

```
function sChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var chart = ss.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
  .addRange(ss.getRange("A1:B20"))
  .setPosition(5,5,0,0)
  .setOption("title","testing option")
  .setOption('trendlines','0: {}')
  .build();  
  ss.insertChart(chart);
}
```

I have also tried the suggestion from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18959510/4277234) post to set the full trendline option first and then call it in the build, but that also produced no difference.

I have also tried different series {0,1,2} with no results.

So: How can I create a scatterplot with a script and insert a trendline at once?

Comment: No :( [HERE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DqE_iibGWUf1LI-9HGGnJoai_57K5BmXNBN9mLzIJrg/edit?usp=sharing) is a test sheet if you want to see/play with it.

Comment: I'd tried 0,1,2 as series, no results for any of them. Nor for your new first suggestion :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a bug with the function.

I got it working by explicitly defining the type as seen below and passing the data as an object, not a string:

```
function sChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var chart = ss.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.SCATTER)
  .addRange(ss.getRange("A1:B20"))
  .setPosition(5,5,0,0)
  .setOption("title", "testing option")
  .setOption("trendlines", {0: {type: "linear"}}) //Defined 'type', pass object not string
  .build();  

  ss.insertChart(chart);
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! So it was missing the "type" declaration? The documentation is pretty sparse, from what I read, so I didn't realize what had to be defined.

Comment: There were 2 things I did differently; the data passed is an object not a string `.setOption('trendlines','0: {}')` --> `.setOption('trendlines',{ 0: {} })`. This still doesnt work (even though it should) so I had to define 'type' as well --> .setOption('trendlines', `{0: {type: "linear"})`.